# Windows 7 installation on laptop freeze

Tags: windows-7, laptop

I tried to install windows 7 on a laptop with XP.
On the **Completing Installation** stage the process stuck.
I restarted, tried to reinstall but got a same result.

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

burn another DVD and try again, if that doesn't help, post back.

and please add make and model of the laptop to your question, thanks.

Comment: Using a slower write speed may help too.

Comment: If you find taht discs still aren't working, you can try using a USB drive to install from. MS provides a tool for making a [Windows 7 USB installer]

  [1]: http://store.microsoft.com/Help/ISO-Tool